# Is it possible to cache content on ionic view with multiple controllers?

Tags: caching, mobile, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that uses tabs and one of the tabs has a view with 2 controllers. When user taps the tab, he sees search results, and when he taps on one of the results, he sees a detailed view of a particular search result.

Tab is setup as follows:

```
.state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})
.state('tab.search', {
url: '/search',
views: {
  'tab-search': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
    controller: 'searchCtrl',
    resolve: {
      data: function(searchService, $stateParams) {
        return searchService.getSearch($stateParams.args);
      }
    }
  }
}
})
.state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home/{user_handle}/{result_id}',
    views: {
      'tab-search': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    resolve: {
      data: function(homeService, $stateParams, $state) {
        return  homeService.getData($stateParams.user_handle, $stateParams.result_id)
            .catch(function(err) {
              if (err.status == 401) { //unauthorized
                $state.go("front");
              } else {
                console.error(err);
              }
            });
      }
    }
      }
    }
})
```

caching is configured as follows:

`$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(10);`

When I tap on the search tab - app makes a call to the backend, when I tap on a search result, app makes a call again, when I go back to search results by taping the back button - call is made again, and when I tap on that same result again - call is made again.

This leads me to believe that view caching isn't working. I am wondering if this is because I have 2 controllers on 1 views. If this makes caching impossible, what are my other options to eliminate useless api calls?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is happening because I am using resolvers and resolvers are not subject to caching. This is what happens when user switches to a cached view:

1. resolver completes
2. controller doesn't load
3. view loads from cache

I am not sure if I want to use resolvers yet as there are some [pitfalls](http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/02/angularjs-pitfalls-using-ui-routers-resolve/). But I am becoming more and more inclined to use some caching library to cache my api calls instead of relying on a view cache.